# Exploding an array for data

Tags: php

I've built the following code and it's doing what I need for the array portion of my code.

```
$demo = '[url=https://www78.zippyshare.com/v/AQg3SYMQ/file.html]1. Like Im Fabo.mp3[/url][url=https://www78.zippyshare.com/v/TPRugyFb/file.html]2. Stic _Em Up.mp3';
$arr = explode("[/url]", $demo);
print '<pre>'; print_r($arr); print '</pre>';
```

The above portion returns this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => [url=https://www78.zippyshare.com/v/AQg3SYMQ/file.html]1. Like Im Fabo.mp3
    [1] => [url=https://www78.zippyshare.com/v/TPRugyFb/file.html]2. Stic _Em Up.mp3
)
```

I am wondering now how I can explode each portion of the above to return something like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://www78.zippyshare.com/v/AQg3SYMQ/file.html
    [0] => 1. Like Im Fabo.mp3
    [1] => https://www78.zippyshare.com/v/TPRugyFb/file.html
    [1] => 2. Stic _Em Up.mp3
)
```

So that I am able to acquire the file path, and the file name with ease.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex for parsing:

```
// Setup regex
$re = '/\[url=(?P<url>[^\]]*)](?P<song>[^\[]*)\[\/url]/';
$str = '[url=https://www78.zippyshare.com/v/AQg3SYMQ/file.html]1. Like Im Fabo.mp3[/url][url=https://www78.zippyshare.com/v/TPRugyFb/file.html]2. Stic _Em Up.mp3[/url]';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

The output will be something like this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(80) "[url=https://www78.zippyshare.com/v/AQg3SYMQ/file.html]1. Like Im Fabo.mp3[/url]"
    ["url"]=>
    string(49) "https://www78.zippyshare.com/v/AQg3SYMQ/file.html"
    [1]=>
    string(49) "https://www78.zippyshare.com/v/AQg3SYMQ/file.html"
    ["song"]=>
    string(19) "1. Like Im Fabo.mp3"
    [2]=>
    string(19) "1. Like Im Fabo.mp3"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(79) "[url=https://www78.zippyshare.com/v/TPRugyFb/file.html]2. Stic _Em Up.mp3[/url]"
    ["url"]=>
    string(49) "https://www78.zippyshare.com/v/TPRugyFb/file.html"
    [1]=>
    string(49) "https://www78.zippyshare.com/v/TPRugyFb/file.html"
    ["song"]=>
    string(18) "2. Stic _Em Up.mp3"
    [2]=>
    string(18) "2. Stic _Em Up.mp3"
  }
}
```

You can iterate through the result set like this:

```
foreach ($matches as $match){
     echo(($match["url"])." => ".($match["song"])."\r\n");
}
```

And the result will be:

```
https://www78.zippyshare.com/v/AQg3SYMQ/file.html => 1. Like Im Fabo.mp3
https://www78.zippyshare.com/v/TPRugyFb/file.html => 2. Stic _Em Up.mp3
```

Comment: Forget to mention: it will work for any number of songs, you just have to iterate through the $matches array like I have shown in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

first trim the [url= of the front of the string using [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) 
then explode the remainder of the string by ]

Answer (score -1):

You should loop over your array, and parse each URL with [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.